# How do I mitigate the situation when Redia has not cached an expensive DB query?

Tags: caching, redis, memcached

Redia has not cached an expensive DB query so that query is running against DB. If unfortunately I get several quests for that query before Redia caches the result, in my current implementation, all the requests go to DB, which makes DB performance downgrade dramatically.

I understand there is probably no easy way to fix this but I was wondering if there is any way to mitigate the situation?

---- update -----

I further google the term **cache stampede** and found these 2 articles informative:

1. [What is a cache stampede and how we solved it by writing our own gem](https://engineering.convertkit.com/2019/10/29/we-built-our-own-cache.html)
2. [How a Cache Stampede Caused One of Facebook’s Biggest Outages](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-a-cache-stampede-caused-one-of-facebooks-biggest-outages-dbb964ffc8ed)

They mentioned following 3 methods to mitigate the situation:

1. locking
2. external recomputation
3. probabilistic early expiration

Answer (score 1):

Normally there are two solutions:

1. Do a prefetch, i.e. do a DB query before the cache expires. You can google the XFetch algorithm for detail.
2. Use a (distributed) lock to avoid the same DB query concurrently hit the DB, i.e. only the client which acquires the lock can do the DB query and update the cache, others have to wait for the result, and try again.

Comment: I didn't know XFetch but when I did search "cache stampede" and found some useful information. Thanks.

Comment: Hi is XFetch the "Probabilistic early recomputation" mentioned here https://betterprogramming.pub/how-a-cache-stampede-caused-one-of-facebooks-biggest-outages-dbb964ffc8ed ?

Comment: Yes, it is. Also check [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1sKn4gWesTw) for integration of XFetch and Redis.